# Java WebService Error: XMLSignatureException - Unsupported signature algorithm found

Tags: java, web-services, ws-security

I need to create a Soap WebService in Java 7 using WS-Security principles. My service needs to handle XML Signing and Encryption.

So far so good, I created the WSDL using the policies and imported it to my Java Web Project.
I created a consumer using jMeter and it worked as excepted.

But now I need to sign the SOAP Message using the following signature algorithm `https://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256`.

My service returns this error message:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <faultcode xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">wsse:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
        <faultstring>com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: Unsupported signature algorithm found</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <ns2:exception xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/" class="javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
                <message>com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: Unsupported signature algorithm found</message>
                <ns2:stackTrace>
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.SOAPUtil" file="SOAPUtil.java" line="202" method="createSOAPFault" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.SOAPUtil" file="SOAPUtil.java" line="194" method="getSOAPFaultException" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityServerTube" file="SecurityServerTube.java" line="304" method="processRequest" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="629" method="__doRun" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="588" method="_doRun" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="573" method="doRun" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="470" method="runSync" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="295" method="process" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="515" method="handle" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="285" method="handle" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="143" method="handle" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="155" method="doGet" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="189" method="doPost" />
                    <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet" file="WSServlet.java" line="76" method="doPost" />
                    <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="650" method="service" />
                    <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="731" method="service" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="303" method="internalDoFilter" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter" file="WsFilter.java" line="52" method="doFilter" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="241" method="internalDoFilter" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve" file="StandardWrapperValve.java" line="219" method="invoke" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve" file="StandardContextValve.java" line="110" method="invoke" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase" file="AuthenticatorBase.java" line="494" method="invoke" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve" file="StandardHostValve.java" line="169" method="invoke" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" file="ErrorReportValve.java" line="104" method="invoke" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" file="AccessLogValve.java" line="1025" method="invoke" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve" file="StandardEngineValve.java" line="116" method="invoke" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter" file="CoyoteAdapter.java" line="445" method="service" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor" file="AbstractHttp11Processor.java" line="1137" method="process" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler" file="AbstractProtocol.java" line="637" method="process" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor" file="JIoEndpoint.java" line="316" method="run" />
                    <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" line="unknown" method="runWorker" />
                    <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker" line="unknown" method="run" />
                    <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable" file="TaskThread.java" line="61" method="run" />
                    <ns2:frame class="java.lang.Thread" line="unknown" method="run" />
                </ns2:stackTrace>
                <ns2:cause class="javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
                    <message>com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: Unsupported signature algorithm found</message>
                    <ns2:stackTrace>
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="1263" method="handleSignature" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="1156" method="processSecurityHeader" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="836" method="createMessage" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="230" method="validateMessage" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase" file="SecurityTubeBase.java" line="462" method="verifyInboundMessage" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityServerTube" file="SecurityServerTube.java" line="277" method="processRequest" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="629" method="__doRun" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="588" method="_doRun" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="573" method="doRun" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="470" method="runSync" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="295" method="process" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="515" method="handle" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="285" method="handle" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="143" method="handle" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="155" method="doGet" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="189" method="doPost" />
                        <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet" file="WSServlet.java" line="76" method="doPost" />
                        <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="650" method="service" />
                        <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="731" method="service" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="303" method="internalDoFilter" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter" file="WsFilter.java" line="52" method="doFilter" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="241" method="internalDoFilter" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve" file="StandardWrapperValve.java" line="219" method="invoke" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve" file="StandardContextValve.java" line="110" method="invoke" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase" file="AuthenticatorBase.java" line="494" method="invoke" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve" file="StandardHostValve.java" line="169" method="invoke" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" file="ErrorReportValve.java" line="104" method="invoke" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" file="AccessLogValve.java" line="1025" method="invoke" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve" file="StandardEngineValve.java" line="116" method="invoke" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter" file="CoyoteAdapter.java" line="445" method="service" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor" file="AbstractHttp11Processor.java" line="1137" method="process" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler" file="AbstractProtocol.java" line="637" method="process" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor" file="JIoEndpoint.java" line="316" method="run" />
                        <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" line="unknown" method="runWorker" />
                        <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker" line="unknown" method="run" />
                        <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable" file="TaskThread.java" line="61" method="run" />
                        <ns2:frame class="java.lang.Thread" line="unknown" method="run" />
                    </ns2:stackTrace>
                    <ns2:cause class="com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
                        <message>javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: Unsupported signature algorithm found</message>
                        <ns2:stackTrace>
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.Signature" file="Signature.java" line="375" method="validate" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="1261" method="handleSignature" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="1156" method="processSecurityHeader" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="836" method="createMessage" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="230" method="validateMessage" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase" file="SecurityTubeBase.java" line="462" method="verifyInboundMessage" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityServerTube" file="SecurityServerTube.java" line="277" method="processRequest" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="629" method="__doRun" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="588" method="_doRun" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="573" method="doRun" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="470" method="runSync" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="295" method="process" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="515" method="handle" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="285" method="handle" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="143" method="handle" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="155" method="doGet" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="189" method="doPost" />
                            <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet" file="WSServlet.java" line="76" method="doPost" />
                            <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="650" method="service" />
                            <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="731" method="service" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="303" method="internalDoFilter" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter" file="WsFilter.java" line="52" method="doFilter" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="241" method="internalDoFilter" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve" file="StandardWrapperValve.java" line="219" method="invoke" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve" file="StandardContextValve.java" line="110" method="invoke" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase" file="AuthenticatorBase.java" line="494" method="invoke" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve" file="StandardHostValve.java" line="169" method="invoke" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" file="ErrorReportValve.java" line="104" method="invoke" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" file="AccessLogValve.java" line="1025" method="invoke" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve" file="StandardEngineValve.java" line="116" method="invoke" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter" file="CoyoteAdapter.java" line="445" method="service" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor" file="AbstractHttp11Processor.java" line="1137" method="process" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler" file="AbstractProtocol.java" line="637" method="process" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor" file="JIoEndpoint.java" line="316" method="run" />
                            <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" line="unknown" method="runWorker" />
                            <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker" line="unknown" method="run" />
                            <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable" file="TaskThread.java" line="61" method="run" />
                            <ns2:frame class="java.lang.Thread" line="unknown" method="run" />
                        </ns2:stackTrace>
                        <ns2:cause class="javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false">
                            <message>Unsupported signature algorithm found</message>
                            <ns2:stackTrace>
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Signature" file="Signature.java" line="184" method="validate" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.Signature" file="Signature.java" line="369" method="validate" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="1261" method="handleSignature" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="1156" method="processSecurityHeader" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="836" method="createMessage" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient" file="SecurityRecipient.java" line="230" method="validateMessage" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase" file="SecurityTubeBase.java" line="462" method="verifyInboundMessage" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityServerTube" file="SecurityServerTube.java" line="277" method="processRequest" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="629" method="__doRun" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="588" method="_doRun" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="573" method="doRun" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="470" method="runSync" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="295" method="process" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="515" method="handle" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="285" method="handle" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="143" method="handle" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="155" method="doGet" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="189" method="doPost" />
                                <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet" file="WSServlet.java" line="76" method="doPost" />
                                <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="650" method="service" />
                                <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="731" method="service" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="303" method="internalDoFilter" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter" file="WsFilter.java" line="52" method="doFilter" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="241" method="internalDoFilter" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain" file="ApplicationFilterChain.java" line="208" method="doFilter" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve" file="StandardWrapperValve.java" line="219" method="invoke" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve" file="StandardContextValve.java" line="110" method="invoke" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase" file="AuthenticatorBase.java" line="494" method="invoke" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve" file="StandardHostValve.java" line="169" method="invoke" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" file="ErrorReportValve.java" line="104" method="invoke" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" file="AccessLogValve.java" line="1025" method="invoke" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve" file="StandardEngineValve.java" line="116" method="invoke" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter" file="CoyoteAdapter.java" line="445" method="service" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor" file="AbstractHttp11Processor.java" line="1137" method="process" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler" file="AbstractProtocol.java" line="637" method="process" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor" file="JIoEndpoint.java" line="316" method="run" />
                                <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor" line="unknown" method="runWorker" />
                                <ns2:frame class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker" line="unknown" method="run" />
                                <ns2:frame class="org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable" file="TaskThread.java" line="61" method="run" />
                                <ns2:frame class="java.lang.Thread" line="unknown" method="run" />
                            </ns2:stackTrace>
                        </ns2:cause>
                    </ns2:cause>
                </ns2:cause>
            </ns2:exception>
        </detail>
    </S:Fault>
</S:Body>
```

I'm starting now with Java and I have no clue what this error is about.
Can anybody help me?

I'm using jdk1.7.0_80, Netbeans and Tomcat 7 for debugging.

Comment: How are you signing the document. Are you using the `javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod`?. You can checl some examples here: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod

Comment: I`m using jmeter to consume my service.